# How to extend the settings file in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using  [Constance - Dynamic Django settings](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#constance-dynamic-django-settings) to configure some values in my project.
according to Constance, I should add all the configurations in the settings.py file.
but I need to separate this configuration in another file.
I tried to extend the settings file by doing the code below, but it didn't work 
it is not reading the value from that new file.

```
from .settings import *


CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS = {
'corres_format_select': ['django.forms.fields.ChoiceField', {
    'widget': 'django.forms.Select',
    'choices': (("xx - xx", "xx - xx"), ("xx/xx", "xx/xx"), ("xx : xx", "xx : xx"))}],

'date_format_select': ['django.forms.fields.ChoiceField', {
    'widget': 'django.forms.Select',
    'choices': (("dd/mm/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy"), ("mm/dd/yyyy", "mm/dd/yyyy"), ("dd-mm-yyyy", "dd-mm-yyyy"))}],
}

CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
'Correspondence_format': ("xx - xx", 'Choose the correspondce format', 'corres_format_select'),
'Date_format': ("dd/mm/yyyy", 'Choose the date format', 'date_format_select'),
}
```

Comment: No, because I need the project to use the default settings.py but i also, need it to read more values from another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write in another file and import into setting file

Comment: yes!  I import the new file in the default settings.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your manage.py, and maybe uwsgi.py file to that new file instead of settings.py.

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't want to replace the setting file I just want to extend it

Comment: Ok that's extremely confusing. Please clarify your intent.